# eGalax touchscreen detects no input in upper part of the screen

Tags: 14.04, xorg, touchscreen, xinput

According to `xinput`, the touch sensor in question is an `EXC7200-7623v1.000`, and is recognized as two slave pointers, one of wich is of type "Pen".

With `xinput test 12` (the non-pen part has the id 12), I get regular event outputs, and Ubuntu even recognises multitouch gestures correctly, but above a certain border, no input is registered. For example, swiping from the bottom to the top of the screen ends in this output:

```
motion a[0]=13744 a[1]=9520
motion a[0]=13744 a[1]=9552
motion a[0]=13744 a[1]=9552
button release 1 a[0]=13744 a[1]=9552
```

At that point, my finger is still on the screen, but moving it has no effect. Tapping in that area has no effect either. The end is variable, too. It lies roughly between  `a[1]=8600` and `a[1]=10200`, depending on the speed of the swipe.

I tried to calibrate the screen with `xinput_calibrator`, but it does not respond to taps on the first crosshair, which is in the upper left part of the screen.

*Is this a driver issue, a problem with X, or could my sensor be broken?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing the display on windows with the same results, I came to notice a hardware defect. The FPC from the sensor to the controller is torn on the lanes that are responsible for the upper part of the screen.

[image]